# How is וּמֵיהוה pronounced

Tags: pronunciation

This might be a stupid question, but I want to confirm וּמֵיהוה is pronounced u-may-adoni. The reason I ask is לַייָ is kind of blended to be la-donoi (the English letters might be a bit off but hopefully people understand what I mean).

Comment: The pronounced name begin with the letter Aleph, that cannot receive a Dagesh. So the Mem is vocalized by a tsere

Comment: לְאָדָ֥ם מַעַרְכֵי־לֵ֑ב וּ֝מֵיְהוָ֗ה מַעֲנֵ֥ה לָשֽׁוֹן:

Comment: מ.ש.ה. מוציא, ו.כ.ל.ב. מכניס

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that when there is a "מ" before Hashem's name the word should be pronounced "u-may-adoni". Only a Mem - Shin - and Hey that are before Hashem's name [מש"ה סימן] have the Alef vocalized. On one of the first pages of an Artscroll siddur they print a box with Hashem's name and how it should be vocalized with different prefixes.

Comment: Also after Hei-Lamed

Comment: @DoubleAA is that the rule? or is the rule that it should be hei-chataf-patach and lamed-patach [even if there's no example that actually follows the rule] and the one in Haazinu is an exception?

Comment: @Heshy I was mostly kidding around, there is no other place such a rule would be relevant afaik